# Separation line between each series in Stacked Chart (Google Charts)

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Stack Chart to generate my report.
Sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/8p6z4631/123/).

The problem here is I need a separation line for each series in the chart.
I tried the below code :

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

dataView.setColumns([0,1,2, {"type": "string","role": "style","calc": ReturnStroke}, 3, {
                "type": "string",
                "role": "style",
                "calc": ReturnStroke
            }, 4, {
                "type": "string",
                "role": "style",
                "calc": ReturnStroke
            }, 5, {
                "type": "string",
                "role": "style",
                "calc": ReturnStroke
            },6,7
            ]);

function ReturnStroke(dataTable, rowNum) {
                return 'stroke-color: #99ebff;';
 }

chart.draw(dataView, options);
```

This worked for me. But the problem here is,it is drawing the border line on four sides of the bar,but I need only on the top side.And also this is just Sample data I have provided.In reality there are about 500 columns in my chart.It is not practical to specify them manually like mentioned above.

Is there any easy way to specify the separation line globally at the chart level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how to change stroke on four sides,
but you can build the view columns dynamically

however, the styles for color and stroke need to be combined into one style column
adding the code posted above to the fiddle,
the stroke style overrides the color style set in the data table

here's an example of how the view columns could be built dynamically...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Machine', '', '', '', '', ''],
    [0.5, null, null, null, null, 0.067],
    [1, 0.05, 0.0775, 0.069, 0.05, 0.067],
    [2, 0.05, 0.0775, 0.069, 0.05, 0.067],
    [2.5, null, null, null, null, 0.067]
  ]);

  var min = data.getColumnRange(0).min;
  var max = data.getColumnRange(0).max;

  var options = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    legend: {
      position: 'none',
      maxLines: 6,
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      4: {
        type: "line",
        color: '#FF0000',
        visibleInLegend: false
      }

    },
    vAxis: {
      baseline: 0,
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [{
        "v": 1,
        "f": "M1"
      }, {
        "v": 2,
        "f": "M2"
      }],

      viewWindow: {
        min: min,
        max: max
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var colors = {
    '1': ['#808080', '#C71585', '#FFC0CB', 'Blue'],
    '2': ['Yellow', 'Pink', '#808080', 'Green']
  };

  var viewColumns = [];
  for (var col = 0; col < data.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
    addColumn(col);
  }
  function addColumn(col) {
    viewColumns.push(col);
    if (col > 0) {
      viewColumns.push({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'style',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          var style = null;
          if ((row > 0) && (row < dt.getNumberOfRows() - 1)) {
            style = 'fill-color: ' + colors[dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)][col - 1] + ';';
            if ((col > 1) && (col < dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 2)) {
              style += ' stroke-color: #99ebff;';
            }
          }
          return style;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);

  chart.draw(dataView, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: You are genius..you have saved me twice in a row :)